# How to write Log Parsing Rule in New Relic using GROK expression for json type message?

Tags: json, regex, logstash-grok, newrelic, grok

Consider my log statement below,

`2020-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00 {message: {statement: "Server Log: Responds!"}, level: 'info'}`

Tried Pattern in https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/,

`%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}`

Result was,

```
{
  "time": [
    [
      "2020-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00"
    ]
  ],
  "logMessage": [
    [
      "{message: {statement: "Server Log: Responds!"}, level: 'info'}"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Expected Result,

```
{
  "time": "2020-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00",
  "logMessage": {
        message: { statement: "Server Log: Responds!" }, 
        level: 'info'
    }
}
```

How to write grok expression for the above logline? Is there any other way to handle this type of logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern that will yield the results that are similar to your expected output:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}%{DATA}{message: *{statement: *"(?<statement>[^"]*)"}, *level: *'(?<level>[^']*)'
```

Testing results:

[image]

Note the use of [named capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) with `(?<name>pattern)` syntax. `[^"]` and `[^']` are [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that match any char other than the char inside the character class.

Comment: This gives an 'Invalid Grok pattern' error as per new relic parsing rule.